# What's happening? Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, dispatch

I came across this error but I can’t understand where I am wrong. I'm pretty new with typescript and redux, and that’s why I can’t manage this.

I probably made some mistakes with the types.

Here it is my interfaces:

```
export interface Action {
    type: string;
    payload: any;
}

export interface Character {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    status: string;
    species: string;
    gender: string;
    image: string;
}
```

actions.ts

```
import { Action } from "../../interfaces/Action"
import { Character } from "../../interfaces/Character"
import { actionT } from "./actionTypes"

export const setCharacters = (characters: Character[]): Action => {
    return {
        type: actionT.SET_CHARACTER,
        payload: characters
    }
}
```

reducers.ts

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { Action } from "../../interfaces/Action";
import { Character } from "../../interfaces/Character";
import { actionT } from "../actions/actionTypes";

const initialState: Character[] = []; 

const characterReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }: Action): Character[] => {
    switch (type) {
        case actionT.SET_CHARACTER:
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const reducers = combineReducers({
    allCharacters: characterReducer
});

export default reducers;
```

and then my component where i fetch some data and then i want to call the dispatch function

```
const allCharacters: Character[] = [];

const CardList = () => {
    const [characters, setCharacters]: [
        Character[],
        (characters: Character[]) => void
    ] = useState(allCharacters);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const fetchCharacters = async () => {
        const response = await axios.post(Constants.ENDPOINT, {
            query: Constants.QUERY,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        });
        setCharacters(response.data.data.characters.results);
        dispatch(setCharacters(characters)) //THERE I HAVE THE ERROR
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchCharacters();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="cards-list">
            test
        </div>
    );
};
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Please try to reduce that code to a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue to others.  Barring that, consider providing a link to a web IDE project that demonstrates the issue.  That lets others immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it, and makes it more likely you'll get a useful answer.

Comment: Is it okay if I attach the gihub link?

Comment: You can, but I won't be cloning it or installing it in my local environment in order to answer a SO question. It's possible someone might come along who's willing to do that, but your goal here should be to lower the bar to entry for people wanting to help.